# Tensorflow memory allocation error: Dst tensor is not initialized - plenty of memory on GPU's

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

When I begin the training of a feedforward 2 layer ANN with GPU on a new cluster using tensorflow, I am greeted by a `Dst tensor is not initialized` error. This error is apparently when there is not enough memory to handle the batch size, however the error states that the allocator ran out of memory while trying to allocate 315.8KiB... this should not be enough to cause a memory error there are no other processes hogging memory on GPU's...

First, `nvidia-smi` shows there are no memory issues or other processes using all memory on my cluster:

```
Wed Apr 11 10:22:49 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 22%   51C    P8    17W / 250W |     65MiB / 12204MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   49C    P8    16W / 250W |     12MiB / 12207MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   48C    P8    16W / 250W |     12MiB / 12207MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   39C    P8    16W / 250W |     12MiB / 12207MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2120      G   /usr/bin/X                                    53MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Traceback below:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *******************************************************xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 315.8KiB.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: zeros_2 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [40416,2] values: [0 0][0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/raid/home/vbalupuri/GDClassifier/scripts/workbench.py", line 52, in <module>
    batch_size=0.5
  File "/raid/home/vbalupuri/GDClassifier/scripts/workbench.py", line 15, in train_classifier
    mlp = ann.Trainer(ann.TwoLayerAnn(dr.xdim[0], dr.ydim[0], 0.1))
  File "gd_classifier/ann/train.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.sess.run(self.init)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: zeros_2 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [40416,2] values: [0 0][0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

InternalError (see above for traceback): Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: zeros_2 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [40416,2] values: [0 0][0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: The error says ~380KiB but that's not the total memory allocated. It's just the one tensor that went overboard. You might very well saturate the memory with thousands of other tensors before that. Try running your training with a terminal running `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` to follow your GPU usage. Then you'll see if your GPU really gets full or not.